# Узлы определённого цвета в GridControl Devexpress

Tags: devexpress

Здравствуйте.
Имеется 2 грида. Сравниваются 2 значения , и если значения 1го больше, то строка сравнения зелёная, другая во 2м гриде красная. Прошёлся циклом (число строк фиксировано), но ранее окрашенные строки становятся прозрачными по умолчанию. То есть окрашивается лишь сфокусированная строка, HideSelectionRow не срабатывает. Как быть???

---

Использую С#. Удалось подкрасить строки через событие RowStyles (предварительно добавив поле в базу данных, динамически в ходе выполнения программы записываются значения и по этим значениям идёт покраска), но встала новая проблема, сфокусированная (не выбранная) строка не окрашивается.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.
Уточните, какую редакцию вы используете (VCL, ASP...).
Для VCL можно использовать следующий вариант:

```
OnCustomDrawCell(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
      ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo;
      var ADone: Boolean);
var
  val1, val2 : Variant;
begin
  if AViewInfo.Selected then exit;

  val1 := VarAsType(AViewInfo.GridRecord.DisplayTexts[Col1.Index], varInteger);
  val2 := VarAsType(AViewInfo.GridRecord.DisplayTexts[Col2.Index], varInteger);
  if (val1 > val2) then begin
    ACanvas.Canvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
    ACanvas.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    ACanvas.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  end;
end;
```

Или же можно использовать AViewInfo.GridRecord.Values вместо DisplayTexts.
В результате если значение val1 > val2, вся строка будет подсвечена желтым цветом.